# Create JSON object and send it to Controller in Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new in `Spring MVC`, `ajax` and `JSON`, so please help me to do the following simple thing: In `JSP` I have an input text field and input button, which must send text's. I need to save this `textbox's` data in **JSON Object** and send it via `jQuery` and `Ajax` to the `Controller`.

[image]

> **Input class**

```
package com.springapp.mvc,model;

public class Input {
    private String input_field;

    public Input(String input_field) {
        this.input_field = input_field;
    }

    public String getInput_field() {
        return input_field;
    }

    public void setInput_field(String input_field) {
        this.input_field = input_field;
    }
}
```

> **hello.js:**

```
<html>
<body>
    <p><input type="text" id="txt" /></p>
    <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="ajax_onclick();"> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show real code...not pictures of code that are hard to read and can't be copied

Answer (score 0):

Use [JQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to send the Json object from the browser.
It should look like this :

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: url, //your controller method url
  type: 'POST',      
  data: {'input_field':'some value'},
  dataType:'json'//try application/json if it doesnt work
  success: function(response) {
  //...
  }
});
```

Comment: and what about in controller part ?